# find all pairs of natural numbers $(x, y)$ so that $121$ divides $x^2+y^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

I have to find all pairs of natural numbers $(x, y)$ so that $121$ divides $$x^2+y^2$$
I thought of writing the amount as equal to $11z$, $z$ natural number. Then I noticed that the numbers must have different parity

Comment: $11$ is a prime of the form $4k+3$, hence both $x$ and $y$ must be divisible by $11$, this gives $(11u,11v)$ with non-negative integers $u,v$ as the set of possible pairs.

Comment: Why? @Peter....

Comment: The squares mod $11$ are $0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9$.  The only pair whose sum $\equiv 0 \mod 11$ is $(0,0)$.

Comment: The only integer solution is the trivial triple $f(11,0)=(121,0,121)$. If zero is excluded, there are no natural number solutions.